# rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-installI

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I 'm using ROS and I'm trying to follow the tutorials on how to export image and video data from a bag file.I keep having this error.When inserting the " rosmake image_view --rosdep-install".What do I lack?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137901/rosmake:-error:-no-such-option:---rosdep-installi/) by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/137886/unable-to-extract-images-from-bag/?answer=137916#post-id-137916

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-11**:
thank you!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-03-11**:
@Leonce, accepting the answer with the check box implicitly marks is as resolved, you don't need to close it in addition.

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-12**:
I'm sorry I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake with --rosdep-install was deprecated several rosdistro's ago.  You now need to invoke rosmake and rosdep independently.

An example can be found here: http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source#fuerte.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-rosinstall.Build_Higher-level.2BAC8-tools_.28Layer_2.29

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-11**:
thank you!